# Fanuc CRX-10iA/L on ROS Noetic

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, fanuc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I’m working on a project that involves a Fanuc CRX-10iA/L robotic arm.

I have Ubuntu 20.04 as a dual boot in my windows machine, but the fanuc_experimental repository doesn’t mention anything about ROS Noetic. What would you say is the easiest, fastest, and least error-prone way out?

1. Back up my data, uninstall Focal and install (dual boot) Bionic/Xenial. In this case, would there be any reason for not choosing Ubuntu Bionic/ROS Melodic over Kinetic when it comes to Fanuc CRX-10iA/L?
2. Keep ubuntu 20.04 and build things from source. Is that even possible?

Would you have any other suggestions?

Edit:

When running the command below according to the [readme in ros-industrial/fanuc](https://github.com/ros-industrial/fanuc/tree/74d7d441311590d3950b03da9a1a86409332c2e8#building) as pointed out by @gvdhoorn that's what I get.

```
theodoro@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ rosdep install --from-paths src/ --ignore-src --rosdistro noetic
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
fanuc_crx10ia_support: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [fanuc_resources]
fanuc_r2000ib_support: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [fanuc_resources]
fanuc_r2000ic_support: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [fanuc_resources]
```

How can I install this dependency?

Thank you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399863/fanuc-crx-10ia/l-on-ros-noetic/) by [Theodoro Cardoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/79961/theodoro-cardoso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2022-04-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-04-28**:
Have you seen the [readme in ros-industrial/fanuc](https://github.com/ros-industrial/fanuc/tree/74d7d441311590d3950b03da9a1a86409332c2e8#building), to which `ros-industrial/fanuc_experimental` refers?

**Comment by [Theodoro Cardoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/79961/theodoro-cardoso/) on 2022-04-28**:
Thank you for your comment, @gvdhoorn. I've been reading a lot of your answers lately and I'm a huge fan of the work you do for the ROS community.

I saw this readme a few minutes after posting the question but was not sure how the "experimental" side of things would play out when it comes to this specific package.

Is building the fanuc_crx10ia_support package possible and supported in ROS Noetic or would you advise me to use ROS Melodic instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is building the fanuc_crx10ia_support package possible and supported in ROS Noetic or would you advise me to use ROS Melodic instead?

I don't believe I can make it any clearer than what the readme states:

> Building the packages on newer (or older) versions of ROS is in most cases possible and supported. For example: **building the packages in this repository on** Ubuntu Bionic/ROS Melodic or **Ubuntu Focal/ROS Noetic systems is supported.**

---

Edit:

> When running the command below according to the [readme in ros-industrial/fanuc](https://github.com/ros-industrial/fanuc/tree/74d7d441311590d3950b03da9a1a86409332c2e8#building) as pointed out by @gvdhoorn that's what I get.

> ```
> theodoro@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ rosdep install --from-paths src/ --ignore-src --rosdistro noetic
> ```

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
fanuc_crx10ia_support: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [fanuc_resources]
fanuc_r2000ib_support: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [fanuc_resources]
fanuc_r2000ic_support: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [fanuc_resources]
```

> How can I install this dependency?

did you *only* `git clone https://github.com/ros-industrial/fanuc_experimental.git`?

If so: that's not enough.

When building `fanuc_experimental` from source, you must also clone `ros-industrial/fanuc` into the same source space.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Theodoro Cardoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/79961/theodoro-cardoso/) on 2022-05-02**:
Thank you, that solved the issue.